# Using multiple where clauses

Tags: sql, where-clause

I have only started using sql maybe a week ago, and of course i'm tasked with pulling data for 177 different entries in the database. To do them one by one, I am currently using the following query.

```
select min(call_date) as First_Call, MAX (call_date) as Last_Call
from dbo.CallHistory (nolock)
where ListID=6635941
```

I'm pulling the earliest and latest call dates for an individual list id. what i'd like to do, is put all my list ids in there and return the list id as well as first and last call dates for each. When i add `ListID` to the select clause, i get an error.

I hope this is clear enough ... please ask if you need additional information.

Comment: `WHERE column = value AND column = value`

Comment: in sql AGGREGATE values need GROUP BY clause...try to add GROUP BY call_date.

Answer (score 4):

```
select listid, 
       min(call_date) as First_Call, 
       max(call_date) as Last_Call 
from   dbo.CallHistory (nolock) 
group by listid
```

Comment: Would I be able to designate which list IDs to pull?  I seem to be dealing with 177 records of 11,000.

Comment: yes, just add `where list id in (1,2,3,4,5,6)` between the `from` and the `group by` lines, but if there's 177 `ListIds` that you're interested in then you'd probably be better off storing those IDs in a separate table and joining to it

Comment: thank you so much for your time!  i went ahead and used a vlookup in excel once i was done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select min(call_date) as First_Call, 
       MAX (call_date) as Last_Call
  from dbo.CallHistory (nolock)
 where ListID in ( 6635941, ....... )
```

**Edit**

As @paqogomez suggested this answer will be usuful when you have a small subset of ids to analyse. Thats because say your database has 20000 registries and you have to analyse just 20 you put those 20 ids and you have your subset.

For all registries you should use the answer provided by paul.

Comment: @paqogomez Won't it? All columns are aggregate functions.

Comment: @paqogomez You dont need a Group By if you are not specifing any column to aggregate.

Comment: @Curt You are correct, my mistake, it still wont give the proper results however.  If you put in multiple listid's it will take the min and max of all the id's, not per id as OP wants.

Comment: @paqogomez With that I agree with you and that's why I think that the OP should choose the answer from paul. I put it just as an option after paul's answer. It would be easier to list, say, 20 registries to analise than 20000.

Comment: @JorgeCampos, if you know your answer to be misleading, it should be edited or removed.

Comment: if i'm to understand correctly ... this will only pull the min / max of this entire list?  as i do require this data for each list id, this definitely wouldn't work for me.

Comment: @siuvhne No this will pull min/max only of the ids you provide. You say on your question that you have to modifi 177 registries and you are running your query one by one. With This answer you will be able to list only the IDs you provide on the IN clause. The `.....` on that parenthesis is the others IDs like `(6635941, 6635942, 6635943, 6635944)` and so on. If  you want to list ALL ids you should use paul answers. But if your database has so many lines you will have a problem because it will list everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select listid,min(call_date) as First_Call, 
       MAX (call_date) as Last_Call
  from dbo.CallHistory (nolock)
 where ListID is not null
group by listid
```